# How can i do the oracle data fix for safe delete in case of foreign key references?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to do data fix on oracle 11g database for my client.

Situation: Rollback when purge the record because of broken references.

Note there is no on cascade delete.

Currently i am doing by inserting the null on broken references manually whenever i get this error for particular record.

So, can someone help me in suggesting solution in  PL/SQL to find the exact solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
declare
  myCnt number := 0;
begin
  for line in
  (
    -- We assume MY_TABLE has T_ID as PK
    select T.T_ID, ...
    from MY_TABLE T
    where <condition to purge records>
  )
  loop
    -- Check for foreign references (we assume MY_OTHER_TABLE
    -- has a FK on MY_TABLE)
    select count(*)
    into myCnt
    from MY_OTHER_TABLE OT
    where OT.T_ID = line.T_ID;

    -- If foreign reference found, exception is raised => no commit
    if myCnt > 0 then
      raise_application_error(...);
    end if;

    -- You can add similar checks on foreign references here
  end loop;

  -- Once we are sure we don't break any reference, perform full delete
  delete
  from MY_TABLE T
  where <condition to purge records>;
end;
/
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your reply @Emmanuel. I have a long inheritance change of parent/child (multilevel). I am not allowed to delete any record. I just need to go through the multilevel chain and fix the reference. I was wondering how can i make it in general without specifying particular table name.

Comment: Ok, could you please add a concrete example with just a few levels ?

Comment: C1
**C2
****C3
****C4
C2
**C3
**C4
C3
C4
P
**C1
****C2
******C3
******C4

Comment: i am not able to add multiple rows. but i can explain. without * is the top level. same number of *'s means at same level.

Comment: this is how i found all the foreign keys select
   cons.owner            as child_owner,*/
   cons.table_name       as child_table,
   col.table_name           parent_table,
   cons.constraint_type     constraint_type,
   col.position             child_position,
   cons.constraint_name     constaint_name
   col.owner                parent_owner,
   col.column_name          column_name*/
from
   dba_cons_columns      col,
   dba_constraints       cons
where
   cons.r_owner = ''
   AND col.owner = ''
   AND cons.r_constraint_name = col.constraint_name order by parent_table;

Comment: but the above script not giving me multilevel chain.